# UIViewPropertyAnimator completion called when paused

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiviewpropertyanimator

I haven’t used `UIViewPropertyAnimator` very much (still an old fashioned blocks guy) and I’m seeing some behavior that I can’t explain and that the docs don’t really provide any insight on.

Why does an animator’s completion block get called with a `finalPosition` of `.end` even when the animator is paused *immediately* after it’s started?

```swift
let view = UIView()
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 4, curve: .linear, animations: {
    view.alpha = 0
})

animator.addCompletion { position in
    print("done")
    switch position {
    case .start: print("start")
    case .current: print("current")
    case .end: print("end")
    }
}

animator.startAnimation()
print("starting")
animator.pauseAnimation()
print("pausing")
```

Output:

```
starting
pausing
done
end
```

Comment: [Session 216 from WWDC 216](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/216/) and [Session 230 from WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/230/) are well worth two hours of your time if you're starting to play with property animators. Really good introductions.

Comment: Thanks for the links — I've seen both of these in the past and will give them another go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as @matt alluded to, is that your view isn't in a visible `UIWindow`, so the animations complete immediately. You get the same output if you comment out the `animator.pauseAnimation()` statement.

You can fix this if you're using a playground by making `view` the `liveView` of the playground page:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let view = UIView()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation of [addCompletion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/1648373-addcompletion) from Apple's developer site,
one of the parameter is the finalPosition. And you can use the value to determine
whether the animation stopped at the beginning, end, or somewhere in the middle.
And calling pauseAnimation will trigger that completion block with a somewhere in the middle position.

> Parameters completion A block to execute when the animations finish.
>   This block has no return value and takes the following parameter:
>
> finalPosition The ending position of the animations. Use this value to
>   determine whether the animations stopped at the beginning, end, or
>   somewhere in the middle.

Comment: That's what I figured, but why would calling `pauseAnimation()` immediately after `startAnimation()` call the completion with a `finalPosition` of `.end`?

Comment: I assuming startAnimation is an async function, so If you are calling the pauseAnimation immediately after that then that would trigger the completion right away. If pauseAnimation will be called via a user-event trigger then you will get a different result I suppose.